# Convert Date format in Unix (AIX)

Tags: unix, timestamp, aix, type-conversion

I have a string which contains a date in the following format:

Wed May 13 13:57:00 1992

I need to convert it into a string with the following format: yyyyMMddHHmmss

Is there any bultin function which does that ?

P.S.
I need it to work on AIX 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `awk` solution that should be portable enough (formatted more for readability):

```
echo "Wed May 13 13:57:00 1992" | tr ':' ' ' | \
  awk 'BEGIN { months["Jan"] = "01"
               months["Feb"] = "02"
               .....
               months["Dec"] = "12"
             }
             { printf "%s%s%s%s%s%s\n", $7, months[$2], $3, $4, $5, $6 }'
```

I would put the `awk` program code in a file though, so I only had to type it once, and I could then do `awk -f convert_date_format.awk` instead...

The `tr` bit isn't really necessary - replacing the colons (or just splitting the time field around them) could be done in `awk`, but it isn't quite as simple as adding the `tr` step...